# Undefined method with “_path” while using simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having problem with routing when using simple_form_for. I understand it is something to do with pluralizing but the same form is working perfectly for edit/update method.

```
undefined method `companies_path'
Did you mean?  companys_path
               company_path
```

**companys_controller**

```
def new
    @company = Company.new
end

def create
    @company = Company.new(company_params)

    if @company.save
        redirect_to @company
    else
        render 'new'
    end

end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @company do |f|
 = f.input :name
 = f.input :description
 = f.input :website

 = f.button :submit
```

**rake routes**

```
    companys GET    /companys(.:format)          companys#index
             POST   /companys(.:format)          companys#create
 new_company GET    /companys/new(.:format)      companys#new
edit_company GET    /companys/:id/edit(.:format) companys#edit
     company GET    /companys/:id(.:format)      companys#show
             PATCH  /companys/:id(.:format)      companys#update
             PUT    /companys/:id(.:format)      companys#update
             DELETE /companys/:id(.:format)      companys#destroy
```

I guess the problem is, Edit/update is going for 'companys_path' and new/create is going for 'companies_path'. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller name should be plural so in your case it should be `companies_controller`

Follow these steps to change it

- Rename controller to `companies_controller.rb`
- Change controller class name to

  ```
  class CompaniesController < ActionController::Base
    # controller code
  end
  ```
- Change in `routes.rb`

  ```
  resources :companies
  ```

**Edit**

**[Controller naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention)**

link in comments by [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6615480/greg-answer)

Comment: But, my model name is 'company', thats not an issue?

Comment: I am not saying about model but controller name

Comment: Rails uses a class called [`Inflector`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) which has a list of standard English pluralizations. The naming convention for Rails is singular model name and plural for the following: table name, controller name, view folder name (based on controller name) and helper names.

This is also briefly explained in [Rails Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention).

Answer (score 1):

First thing,  you should follow `rails` naming convention and rename your controller from `companys_controller.rb` to `companies_controller.rb`.
Your issue will be fixed after renaming.

`Simple form` taking assumption that you have followed rails naming convention and making request at `companies_path` which is not present in your `routes`.